# Odd issue with Python, Django and stdout

Tags: python, mysql, django, linux, unix

I was wondering if I could get some help with the code I pasted below. Right now it runs and completes the ping task however it runs into the following error. Any help would be great as I have been working on it for a while now.

Error:

```
    Server.objects.filter(pk=id[0]).update(online=1)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Code:

```
import subprocess
from django.db import models
from networkstats.models import Server

query = Server.objects.values_list('id', 'ip_address')
for ip_address in query:
    print 'Server ID: ' + str(ip_address[0])
    print 'Server IP: ' + str(ip_address[1])
    command = ['ping -t 200 -c 1 ' + ip_address[1]]
    ping = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    if "100% pocket loss" in ping.stdout.read():
        Server.objects.filter(pk=id[0]).update(online=0)
    else:
        Server.objects.filter(pk=id[0]).update(online=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo. Did you want to write `ip_address[0]` instead of `id[0]`?

`id` is a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id), because of it you get this error.

Also look at probably better implementation of your code snippet:

```
for server in Server.objects.only('ip_address', 'id').all():
    print 'Server ID: ' + str(server.id)
    print 'Server IP: ' + str(server.ip_address)

    command = ['ping -t 200 -c 1 ' + server.ip_address]
    ping = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    online = 1
    if "100% pocket loss" in ping.stdout.read():
        online = 0

    server.update(online=online)
```

This will fetch only needed rows (if there are others) and reduce traffic to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that change and correcting "pocket loss" allows it to update correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it `ip_address[0]` and not `id[0]` you're looking for?